# Right method to store data in a database

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

[image: Type1]

[image: Type2]

[image: Type3]

I would like to know what is the best way to store a data in a database? Excuse me for my ignorance.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images or links to images.

Comment: Can you provide description of data you want to store and what exactly you trying to achieve?

Comment: Say I want to store 3 subjects for a particular student. Should I use three columns like  Sub1 Sub2 Sub3 or I should use 3 row for the same students in a common column Sub or I should store in a single row and column seperated by comma say

Comment: It would be best to do some research into how databases work and what database normalization is. Here's a link to get you started. https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/

Comment: By database I assume you mean a Relational database.  You want to achieve at a minimum 3rd normal form (3NF).  This design ensures data isn't duplicated, adding data is preferable to adding rows. Key's are used to uniquely identify records, and relationships between data are properly established.  So adding data is preferable to adding new columns.

Answer (score -1):

You can seperate the table for Student Enrolled and Student Information, since student can have more than one enrollment.

```
student_information {student_id(pk), firstname, lastname, dob}
student_enrolled {enrollment_id(pk), student_id(fk), programme, code, schedule}
```

On these two tables you can store one to many enrollment per student (1st level, 2nd level and so on)